# Issue with intercepting requests to controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, controller

I want to create an abstract controller that will add the additional request mapping basen on actual mappings for the extending controller.

As an example, for the following controller

```
@Controller
public class MyController extends VariableResolvingController {
    @RequestMapping("page.htm") 
    public void handlerMethod() {
    }
}
```

I want it to extend `VariableResolvingController`that will add a mapping to it's `resolveContextVariable(...)` method with the "page.htm.context" URI.

```
public abstract class VariableResolvingController {
    public final @ResponseBody Object resolveContextVariable(String variableName) {
        return "{}";
    }

    protected final void registerVariableResolver(String variableName, VariableResolver resolver) {
        //...
    }
}
```

This approach adds a possibility to resolve custom variables using eg. AJAX requests in a way almost transparent for a client code.

Do you know any existing solutions that would be appropriate in this case?

**Solution:** I achieved my goal by writing a custom [HandlerMapping](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerMapping.html) implementation (in essence a decorator for [RequestMappingHandlerMapping](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/RequestMappingHandlerMapping.html)).

Comment: I don't think that anything of this is actually necessary. Spring ignores suffixes per default and instead of calling `resolveContextVariable()` yourself you can let Spring handle it, e.g. by annotating it with `@ModelAttribute`. You can get a better solution if you describe the underlying problem. What you are asking for is bad design.

Answer (score 2):

One way of doing is add simple Servlet filter to your spring mvc

```
 public class RequestCheckFilter implements Filter {

        @Override
        public void destroy() {
            // ...
        }

        @Override
        public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException         {
            //
        }

        @Override
        public void doFilter(ServletRequest request,
                   ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {

            try {
                HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = ((HttpServletRequest) request);
            String requestURI = httpServletRequest.getRequestURI();

            if (requestURI.endsWith(".context")) {
                request.getRequestDispatcher(requestURI.concat(".htm"))
                    .forward(request,response);
            } else {
                chain.doFilter(httpServletRequest, response);
            }
       } catch (Exception ex) {
            request.setAttribute("errorMessage", ex);
            request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/views/jsp/error.jsp")
                           .forward(request, response);
       }

}
```

add it

```
public class MyWebInitializer extends
        AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    //...

    @Override
    protected Filter[] getServletFilters() {
        return new Filter[]{new RequestCheckFilter()};
    }
}
```

or in web.xml

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>reqHandlerFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>RequestCheckFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>reqHandlerFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```